# Why does some code use define() without quoting the constant name?

Tags: php, constants

The PHP's documentation describes `define()` function with the constant name as a string. So it should be in quotes:

```
define('ANY_CONSTANT',1);
```

However I saw tons of examples with no quotes like this:

```
define(ANY_CONSTANT,1);
```

I also tested both ways in [online PHP tester](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and both worked correctly.

Can anyone explain a little bit: is there any difference between those two methods? Is any of those better? In which circumstances?

Comment: Enable error reporting. The latter spits out a notice. Also I doubt you found "tons" of examples

Comment: You should have quotes around the name in the define statement, but use the name unquoted in the rest of your script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Yes you should.

If you don't, PHP will look for a constant with that name, not find one, and assume it's a string and use it as such. This will generate a notice in the error log, if you set PHP to report notices.

Comment: I saw somewhere in the mailing lists someone talked about the plans to get rid of that behaviour in php 7+

Answer (score 1):

Using

> define(ANY_CONSTANT,1);

will cause a warning:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ANY_CONSTANT - assumed
>   'ANY_CONSTANT'

So you definitely need to use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

(As always) It depends on the context:

```
define(ANY_CONSTANT,1);
```

is legal, since passing a literal (such as `'ANY_CONSTANT'`) is not mandatory - you could also pass a constant (such as `PHP_OS` aswell). You have to make sure not mixing up literals with constants.

Why it "works" for you is a dangerous approach, since in one case you might have simply forgot the quotation, but in another case you'd definitly wanted to use a constant. Hence the notices PHP will throw.